# ValueConverter not called on start up

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I have combobox that is bound to a collection. Each item in the collection has a subcollection that might or might not contain items. I have a second combobox to which the subcollection is bound. And I only want to display (=Visibility.Visible) the second combobox if the subcollection has items. All that works. BUT: When I start my program, the selectedItem of the main combobox is null (=so far nothing has been selected). This (I guess) causes the converter to not be called (it doesn't, I have set a breakpoint on the converter and the program does not halt when it starts).

So I have the problem that I don't want to display the second combobox when the program starts. Can I force the ValueConverter to be called? I have tried invoking OnPropertyChanged at the end of the constructor, but that doesn't change anything. And when I set the combobox to Visible.Hidden in the constructor of the .xaml.cs, it will not show at all, even after the value converter is called. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting a `FallbackValue` for the binding? When there is nothing bound you can set a value that will be used in place of the binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a `FallbackValue` for the binding:

```
<SomeUIElement Visibility="{Binding SomeBinding, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, FallbackValue=Hidden}" />
```

When there is nothing bound you can set a value that will be used in place of the binding.

The reason changing the value in code-behind to `Visibility.Hidden` leaves it invisible all the time is because setting the property explicitly removes the binding that you have added in the XAML

Comment: Perfect answer in less than 5 minutes. I love SOF! Thanks a lot!